# Is it true that: $\frac {1 } {10 }(\sin(y_1+y_2)-\sin(x_1+x_2)+y_2-x_2)^2+(\cos(x_1+x_2)-\cos(y_1+y_2)+x_1-y_1)^2) \le (y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Is it true that:

$$\frac {1 } {10 }\left(\left(\sin(y_1+y_2)-\sin(x_1+x_2)+y_2-x_2\right)^2+\left(\cos(x_1+x_2)-\cos(y_1+y_2)+x_1-y_1\right)^2\right) \le (y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2$$

I think I should be able to use that the trigonometric functions are bounded, but I need som help.

Thanks in advance!